# how is MalformedURLException thrown in Java

Tags: java, protocols, malformedurlexception

I mean, how does Java decide which protocols are available? I run some code from inside Eclipse, and it works just fine. Then I run the same code from outside Eclipse, and I get "unknown protocol" MalformedURLException. Probably it has to do with the code base, or something? Any hints would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: What protocals? Better yet, what URLs are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work of resolving the protocol is done by the [`URLStreamHandler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html), which are stored in `URL.handlers` by protocol in lowercase. The handler, in turn, is created by the [`URLStreamHandlerFactory`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory.html) at `URL.factory`. Maybe eclipse is monkeying with that?

Some of the [URL constructors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.net.URLStreamHandler)) take stream handlers and you can set the factory with [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory(java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory)).

Here's a web post about [developing protocol handlers](http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/JAVA-Developers-Guide/ch29.htm).

Comment: The URL is some custom URL ("media:///") which should be handled by the application.

Comment: You are definitely right. I could locate the code that does just what you say. Now it all makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The java standard way of defining protocol handlers is described here: 
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/

This relies on the protocol handler class being available on the boot (?) classloader. That doesn't work well with OSGi (and thus Eclipse). OSGi provides a wrapper around this mechanism to allow bundles/plugins to contribute protocol handlers.
See: http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v41/org/osgi/service/url/URLStreamHandlerService.html

Eclipse also provides its own protocol: bundle-resource (iirc) which definitely won't work outside of Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a classpath issue.  If you are using a protocol that depends on some library (jar) you included, and then exported a JAR from eclipse, the JAR files you included in your project are probably not being found by the running code outside of eclipse.  You need a manifest file in your jar that will point to the libraries that are needed.